# SQL - Finding the most common value, in a column, for different sets in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with two tables; **[Clients]** and **[Transactions]**. I have a foreign key assigned to either one or multiple records in the **[Transactions]** table that relates to the **[Clients]** table.

In the **[Transactions]** table, I have a field, called 'URL', that is populated with URLs (it is what it says on the tin). I want to go through all the records in the **[Transactions]** table and find out which is the most common value in the **'URL'** field for each of the sets associated with the **[Clients]** table.

Once I have the most common values, I want to insert them into the **[Clients]** table, in a field called **'URL'** (just like in the **[Transactions]** table), against the associated Client record.

I'm sure I could figure most of it out, my only problem is with finding the most common values for many different small groups. Any help is appreciated!

***SAMPLE DATA:***

```
[Clients]

ID          Name               URL
-----------------------------------
999999999   Testing Client 1   NULL
999999998   Testing Client 2   NULL
999999997   Testing Client 3   NULL
999999996   Testing Client 4   NULL
999999995   Testing Client 5   NULL


[Transactions]

ID      ClientID    URL
-----------------------------------------
73611   999999999   http://www.google.com
73612   999999999   http://www.yahoo.com
73613   999999999   http://www.google.com
73626   999999998   http://www.stackoverflow.com
73627   999999998   http://www.stackoverflow.com
73628   999999998   http://www.slack.com
73629   999999997   http://www.dotnetpearls.com
73630   999999997   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com
73631   999999996   http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk
73632   999999996   http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk
73633   999999996   http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk
73634   999999996   NULL
73635   999999995   NULL
73636   999999995   http://www.w3schools.com
73637   999999995   http://www.w3schools.com
```

Comment: most common value like what?

Comment: @reds The sample data shows that there are multiple URLs associated to a single Client record. For example, for ClientID = 999999999, there are 3 URLs. The most common URL here is "http://www.google.com". I want to get this information for every single different ClientID.

Comment: What if client have multiple most common values, like 3 times "google" and 3 times "yahoo"? do you want both ?

Comment: So, there most common for 999999998 is "http://www.stackoverflow.com", and the most common for 999999996 is "http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk", etc.

Comment: @Oto In that case, the first one will do. I only want the most common if there are more of one than any other. If not, the first will do.

Comment: 999999997   has 2 different urls, how would you determine which one is most common among these two.

Comment: @Kapil The most common in that case would be impossible to determine, as there isn't a most common, the first value will have to do.

Comment: Specify the expected result - as formatted text. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Which SQL Server version?

Comment: It's okay, I have done what was needed to be done. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will update the Clients table with the most common URL:

```
update Clients
set Clients.URL = x2.URL
from(
    --This takes the inner query and sorts the rows according to the URLCount (descending), assigning a rank (using the row_number() function).
    --The highest URLCount will be given a URLRank of 1.  The URLRank resets for each client (partition by clientID).
    select ClientID, URL, row_number() over (partition by clientID order by URLCount desc) URLRank
    from(
        --This groups the clients, giving one row for each client/URL combo, along with how many times that combo occurs.
        select t.ClientID, t.URL, Count(1) URLCount
        from Transactions t
        group by t.ClientID, t.Url
        ) x
) x2
where x2.URLRank = 1  --Set the URL to the highest ranking URL
and Clients.ID = x2.ClientID
```

If you just want to see what the most common URL is for each client, use this:

```
select *
from(
    select ClientID, URL, row_number() over (partition by clientID order by URLCount desc) URLRank
    from(
        select t.ClientID, t.URL, Count(1) URLCount
        from Transactions t
        group by t.ClientID, t.Url
        ) x
) x2
where x2.URLRank = 1
```

Comment: Also, would it be alright if you could explain exactly what this query is doing so that I can fully understand it?

Comment: I've added some inline comments to the SQL.

Comment: Thank you, Jerrad!

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 `CTE` like this

```
;WITH temp as 
(
    SELECT cl.ID as ClientID, t.URL, COUNT(t.ID) as NumberTransactions  
    FROM  Clients cl
    LEFT JOIN [Transactions] t on cl.ID = t.ClientID
    GROUP BY cl.ID, t.URL
), 
temp1 as
(
    SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.ClientID ORDER BY t.NumberTransactions desc) as Rn
    FROM temp t
)

SELECT t.ClientID, t.URL
FROM temp1 t
WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#client') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #client
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#transactions') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #transactions

CREATE TABLE #client (id INT, name VARCHAR(100), url VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE #transactions (id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), clientID INT, url VARCHAR(100));

INSERT #client
        ( id, name, url )
VALUES  ( 9, 'a', null ),
        ( 8, 'b', null ),
        ( 7, 'c', null ),
        ( 6, 'd', null ),
        ( 5, 'e', null );

INSERT #transactions
        ( clientID, url )
VALUES  (9,   'http://www.google.com'                ),
        (9,   'http://www.yahoo.com'                 ),
        (9,   'http://www.google.com'                ),
        (8,   'http://www.stackoverflow.com'         ),
        (8,   'http://www.stackoverflow.com'         ),
        (8,   'http://www.slack.com'                 ),
        (7,   'http://www.dotnetpearls.com'          ),
        (7,   'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com'         ),
        (6,   'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'     ),
        (6,   'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'     ),
        (6,   'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'     ),
        (6,   NULL                                   ),
        (5,   NULL                                   ),
        (5,   'http://www.w3schools.com'             ),
        (5,   'http://www.w3schools.com'             );
```

This query would get the count of each url per clientID. We do however get one row per transaction

```
SELECT 
         urlCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY clientID, url)
       , transactionURL = t.URL
       , t.clientID
FROM #transactions t
```

From that query we only want the highest `urlCount`, which we get by ordering on `urlCount DESC` and getting the TOP 1. We do want to get this top counted URL *per client*.

We can do that by using cross apply, to run this count and top 1 for each client. Cross apply will run the inner query once per row in the client table. The inner query is filtered on client.ID to get the urlCount for that client.

The inner query is sorted by urlCount DESC to get the highest counted URL (per client). As a tie-breaker it is also sorted on transactions.ID - this is done so that it would produce the same result each time it was run.

```
  SELECT c.url, transURLs.transactionURL, c.id
    FROM #client c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 
                 urlCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY clientID, url)
               , transactionURL = t.URL
        FROM #transactions t
        WHERE t.clientID = c.ID
        ORDER BY urlCount DESC, t.id
    ) transURLs
```

To wrap it up we simply update

```
WITH baseData AS (
    SELECT c.url, transURLs.transactionURL, c.id
    FROM #client c
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 
                 urlCount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY clientID, url)
               , transactionURL = t.URL
        FROM #transactions t
        WHERE t.clientID = c.ID
        ORDER BY urlCount DESC, t.id
    ) transURLs
)
UPDATE baseData 
SET url = transactionURL;

SELECT * FROM #client
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very detailed. I always prefer an answer that goes more in depth and isn't just the solution in a code block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with ctetbl (clientid,url,cnt,rowid) As 
(
Select t.clientid, t.url,t.cnt,
ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by clientid order by t.cnt desc)as RowId 
from (select  clientid,url, COUNT(1)as cnt from transactions group by clientid,url)t 
)
Update c
set url=ct.url
from clients c
inner join 
ctetbl ct on c.id=ct.clientid where rowid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*************Script to recreate the scenario *************/

Create table [Clients]
(
    Id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    Name nvarchar(100),
    URL nvarchar(1000)
)

Insert into Clients VALUES
(999999999,'Testing Client 1',NULL),
(999999998,'Testing Client 2',NULL),
(999999997,'Testing Client 3',NULL),
(999999996,'Testing Client 4',NULL),
(999999995,'Testing Client 5',NULL)

Create table Transactions
(
    ID bigint,
    ClientID bigint FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Clients(ID),
    URL nvarchar(1000)
)
Insert into Transactions VALUES
(73611,   999999999,'http://www.google.com'),
(73612,   999999999,'http://www.yahoo.com'),
(73613,   999999999,'http://www.google.com'),
(73626,   999999998,'http://www.stackoverflow.com'),
(73627,   999999998,'http://www.stackoverflow.com'),
(73628,   999999998,'http://www.slack.com'),
(73629,   999999997,'http://www.dotnetpearls.com'),
(73630,   999999997,'http://www.c-sharpcorner.com'),
(73631,   999999996,'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'),
(73632,   999999996,'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'),
(73633,   999999996,'http://www.roastmymealdeal.co.uk'),
(73634,   999999996,NULL),
(73635,   999999995,NULL),
(73636,   999999995,'http://www.w3schools.com'),
(73637,   999999995,'http://www.w3schools.com')

/***************List the tables *****************/

Select * from dbo.Clients
Select * from dbo.Transactions
/***************************************************************************************
cte_grp1 -- 
    Using window functions find the ClientID and URL and number of times it is found in Transaction
cte_grp2
    In second step, just find out the ones with maximum count and rank them accordingly
    Store the result into another table
**************************************************************************************/
;with cte_grp1
as
(
    SELECT
        ClientID,
        URL,
        Count(URL) as CountOfURL
    FROM Transactions
    WHERE URL IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ClientID,URL
--  Order by ClientID ASC,CountOfURL DESC
),
cte_grp2
as
(
    SELECT  y.ClientID,
            y.URL,
            x.MaxCount  
    FROM cte_grp1 y 
    INNER JOIN 
    (Select ClientID,URL,Max(CountOfURL) as MaxCount
    FROM cte_grp1
    Group by ClientID,URL ) x 
    ON x.ClientId=y.ClientID and x.URL=y.URL
    --Order by y.ClientID,x.MaxCount DESC
)
Select ClientID,URL,MaxCount,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY MaxCount DESC) as Rnk
INTO #Temp_Resultant
from cte_grp2

/*******************************************************************
  Using this temp table we will be using FOR XML clause for those links
  where a Client has visited the link one time each as they both quality 
  to be updated in the Clients table

  At last.. Update based on ClientID
************************************************************************/

;with resultant
as
(
Select distinct t2.ClientID,STUFF((SELECT ','+ t1.URL 
              FROM #Temp_Resultant t1 
              WHERE Rnk=1
              AND t1.ClientID=t2.ClientID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') as CommonURL
From #Temp_Resultant t2
)
Update A
SET A.URL=B.CommonURL
FROM Clients A INNER JOIN resultant B
ON A.Id=B.ClientID

---Check the results
Select * from Clients
Select * from Transactions
```